Do we need the communication tag?
I recently noticed the communication tag.  Should that tag exist?  It seems to me like it is not very helpful.  We could probably tag half or more of our questions with communication, which suggests that it is overbroad.
Currently, there are 5 questions tagged communication.  I think we could remove the communication tag from all of them, without any serious loss, and delete the communication tag.
What do you think?


Secure communication between multiple peers on a public channel → key-exchange and maaaaybe a new secure-channel tag
Can cryptography be used to hide routing information from the router? → I see the point, in that the question is about managing communication, as opposed to communicating. But the tag name is bad. onion-routing may be enough anyway.
Snowden Challenge II: Can we solve Snowden challenge quantumly? → yeah-whatever
Encrypted counter as IV in CBC mode encryption using same key → useless tag
Security of CFB on a public channel → again, maaaaybe secure-channel

So let's get rid of communication. Is secure-channel a worthwhile tag, or is it still too broad?

[tag:secure-channel] seems reasonable to me.

I did go ahead and removed the communication tag, replacing it at three points with secure-channel, as proposed by Gilles.
Thanks for the find.

I would agree to delete it. 
Looking across the questions at crypto.SE, more than half of them touch the communication tag in some way, rendering the tag more general and thereby less useful. Maybe if the type of communication involved would be narrowed down, such a tag could make sense... but there's rarely base to really define the type of communication, so we might as well get rid of the more general communication tag as well. 
At least, that's what I think about it.
